# Is Magento2 EE a right solution for 100M of products?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, catalog, magento-2.1, magento2-enterprise

We are in the middle of our decision making process to go with Magento2 or develop our own solution. We have around 90M products and want to know if Magento2 EE is a right platform to support this number of products or we should write our own solution ?

Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: Just to make sure 90M means 90.000.000 products?

Comment: @Marius Yes.....

Comment: "develop our own solution" is a pretty bad idea most of the time, so as a general rule don't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

90M products it's not a problem for Magento2 EE.

I know one project with tested up to 100M products on M2, but to be honest, its customized solution for a concrete client.

Some advanced functionality was fully removed and some critical code was rewritten (like indexation)  ~ 20 classes. And this was tested on proper infrastructure.

So, I recommend using Magento2 EE as a base for your project.